# How to scale and move in the same time?

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following code which is scaling the div on mouseover but in the same time I want to move it 10px to top? Is there any way to do it?

Thanks

```
.ad{
    background: url(frame.jpg);
    width: 980px;
    height: 50px;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
$('.banner').on('mouseover', function() {
    var val = 0.4;
    $(".ad").css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + val + ')',
        '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + val + ')',
        '-ms-transform': 'scale(' + val + ')',
        '-o-transform': 'scale(' + val + ')',
        'transform': 'scale(' + val + ')'
    });
});
```

Comment: Why use Javascript here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use addClass method of Jquery like:

**In javascript**

```
.ad{
        background: url(frame.jpg);
        width: 980px;
        height: 50px;
        transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    }
$('.banner').on('mouseover', function() {
            var val = 0.4;
            $(".ad").addClass("ad-fly");
        });
```

**In CSS**

```
.ad-fly{
    -webkit-transition-duration:1s;
    -webkit-transform:scale(0.4) translateY(10px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add every transformations in the same property, like :

```
'transform': 'scale(' + val + ') translateY(-10px);'
```

*(same for vendor prefixed properties)*

Answer (score 1):

Do it on pure CSS:
http://codepen.io/ArthyFiciel/pen/JYaYew

```
.ad:hover{
  transform: translate(0, -10px) scale(0.4);
}
```

In your case :

```
.banner:hover .ad { /***/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you add another css statement to your function

```
$('.banner').on('mouseover', function() {
                var val = 0.4;
                $(".ad").css({
                    '-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + val + ')',
                    '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + val + ')',
                    '-ms-transform': 'scale(' + val + ')',
                    '-o-transform': 'scale(' + val + ')',
                    'transform': 'scale(' + val + ')',
                    'margin-top': '-10px'
                });
            });
```